# SpsiteDataquery update values to List by uniqueid

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

[image]

Were i dislay the title and date are a Gridview when pressing the title that uniqueid shows and the information are displayed, but also just to that UniqueId that i display i want to add Nickname and comments (Userinput) and save back to the list there i have the columns nickname and comments
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried committing the changes back to SharePoint?

```
itemToUpdate["Nickname"] = TextBoxName.Text;
itemToUpdate["_Comments"] = TextBoxComment.Text;
itemToUpdate.Update();
```

## Edit

It's hard for me to make out what you're asking here.

If you're trying to query against the `SPListItem.UniqueId`, it's a `Guid`, not an `int`.

```
query.Query = "<Where>" +
                "<Eq>" +
                  "<FieldRef Name='UniqueId'/>" +
                  "<Value Type='Guid'>" + theUniqueId + "</Value>" +
                "</Eq>" +
              "</Where>";
```

Also, those extra gators (`"<" + listItemId + "/>"`) in your query will cause the query to fail to parse.

Comment: @ rjcup3 that not the problem i dont know how to use spsitedataquery to get items by id ,

Comment: I edited my answer to address this.

Comment: @jcup3 okej , but do spsitedataquery support splistitem?

Comment: It's for queries against multiple lists. If you're only querying one list, just use `SPQuery`.